# View Preview Correct , Actual Page Not

Tags: views, panels

I have a block view that I am placing in every page containing the content type "class". There are several "lesson" content types referencing it through entity reference "field_class".

I want the view to display all lessons referencing the class.

I set my view up like so:[image: Content entity referenced from field_class is the relationship being used.]

When I pass the args through it, it displays correctly, as in the first image.

When I go to the same page whose node id I passed through the view preview to get a correct output, I find that the page is displaying something different:
[image: The result showing is the "no results" default summary]

The result showing is the "no results" default summary.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or suggest advice to clear up the problem?

I'm using drupal 7. To place the block in the page I'm using panelizer.
I'm not using any internationalization modules

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the screenshot of my contextual filter:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the filter to "Provide default value", and then choose the node ID from the URL.